# Flatten Ruby Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an Array which looks like this.

`[{"title"=>"ga:browser=Internet Explorer", "dimensions"=>[{:browser=>"Internet Explorer"}], "metrics"=>[{:pageviews=>2047}], "id"=>"http://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga:12316&ga:browser=Internet%20Explorer&start-date=2010-02-27&end-date=2011-02-27", "updated"=>#}, {"title"=>"ga:browser=Safari", "dimensions"=>[{:browser=>"Safari"}], "metrics"=>[{:pageviews=>1196}], "id"=>"http://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga:12316&ga:browser=Safari&start-date=2010-02-27&end-date=2011-02-27", "updated"=>#}, {"title"=>"ga:browser=Firefox", "dimensions"=>[{:browser=>"Firefox"}], "metrics"=>[{:pageviews=>835}], "id"=>"http://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga:12316&ga:browser=Firefox&start-date=2010-02-27&end-date=2011-02-27", "updated"=>#}, {"title"=>"ga:browser=Chrome", "dimensions"=>[{:browser=>"Chrome"}], "metrics"=>[{:pageviews=>227}], "id"=>"http://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga:12316&ga:browser=Chrome&start-date=2010-02-27&end-date=2011-02-27", "updated"=>#}, {"title"=>"ga:browser=Mozilla Compatible Agent", "dimensions"=>[{:browser=>"Mozilla Compatible Agent"}], "metrics"=>[{:pageviews=>60}], "id"=>"http://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga:12316&ga:browser=Mozilla%20Compatible%20Agent&start-date=2010-02-27&end-date=2011-02-27", "updated"=>#}, {"title"=>"ga:browser=Opera", "dimensions"=>[{:browser=>"Opera"}], "metrics"=>[{:pageviews=>33}], "id"=>"http://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga:12316&ga:browser=Opera&start-date=2010-02-27&end-date=2011-02-27", "updated"=>#}, {"title"=>"ga:browser=BlackBerry9700", "dimensions"=>[{:browser=>"BlackBerry9700"}], "metrics"=>[{:pageviews=>8}], "id"=>"http://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga:12316&ga:browser=BlackBerry9700&start-date=2010-02-27&end-date=2011-02-27", "updated"=>#}, {"title"=>"ga:browser=BlackBerry8900", "dimensions"=>[{:browser=>"BlackBerry8900"}], "metrics"=>[{:pageviews=>7}], "id"=>"http://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga:12316&ga:browser=BlackBerry8900&start-date=2010-02-27&end-date=2011-02-27", "updated"=>#}, {"title"=>"ga:browser=Mozilla", "dimensions"=>[{:browser=>"Mozilla"}], "metrics"=>[{:pageviews=>2}], "id"=>"http://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga:12316&ga:browser=Mozilla&start-date=2010-02-27&end-date=2011-02-27", "updated"=>#}, {"title"=>"ga:browser=Camino", "dimensions"=>[{:browser=>"Camino"}], "metrics"=>[{:pageviews=>1}], "id"=>"http://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga:12316&ga:browser=Camino&start-date=2010-02-27&end-date=2011-02-27", "updated"=>#}]`

Is there a simple way to flatten it so that it becomes:

`[2047,1196,835,227,60,33,8,7,2,1]`

and also

`['Internet Explorer','Firefox','Chrome','Mozilla Compatible Agent','Opera','BlackBerry9700','Mozilla','Camino']`

Comment: That's not going to be easy to read...

Comment: Is there an easy way to pretty print .inspect?

Comment: `require 'pp'; puts your_array.pretty_inspect` or `require 'pp'; pp your_array`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assign your Array to `data`

```
pageviews = data.map{|d| d["metrics"][0][:pageviews]} #= [2047, 1196...]

browsers = data.map{|d| d["dimensions"][0][:browser]} #= ['Internet Explorer', 'Firefox', ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Flatten produces an Array. I am wondering, though, it seems like for output maybe you really want a hash that has arrays as the values?  Is that what you are looking for?

{'title'=>["ga:browser=Internet Explorer", "ga:browser=Safari"]}

If so, something like this might work (with arr being your array):

```
newdata=arr.inject({}) do |memo,subhash|
  subhash.each do |key,val|
    memo[key] ||= []
    memo[key] << val
  end
  memo
end

puts newdata.inspect

puts newdata['title'].inspect
```